# Caroufredsel not centring on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, caroufredsel

After many weeks of trying I have finally gotten my caroufredsel carousel centring on computers,  only to discover that it still isn't doing so on mobile devices (smart phone and tablets).  Please can anybody help.

The website is http://www.suffolkwindowbox.co.uk - there are different sliders on most pages but they all have the same settings.

The caroufredsel is the plugin.

The script is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {                
    function runCarousel() {                        
    $("#caroufredsel-keCZE-266").carouFredSel({ 
        circular:   true,
        infinite:   true,
        responsive: false,
        direction:  "left",
        align:  "center",
        width:  "100%",
        height: 560,
        items: {
           visible: 3,
           start: -1,
        },
        scroll: {
           items: 1,
           fx:          "scroll",
           easing:  "swing",
           duration:     1000,
           pauseOnHover: true,
        },
        auto: {
          play: true,
          timeoutDuration:  5000,
        },
        prev: {
          button: "#dev7-caroufredsel-wrapper-keCZE-266 .dev7-caroufredsel-prev",
          key:           null,
        },
        next: {
          button: "#dev7-caroufredsel-wrapper-keCZE-266 .dev7-caroufredsel-next",
          key:          null,
        },

        pagination: { container:    "#dev7-caroufredsel-wrapper-keCZE-266 .dev7-caroufredsel-pag", anchorBuilder   : null, },
        swipe: { onTouch:   true },

    });     
    }                                               
    $("#caroufredsel-keCZE-266").imagesLoaded(runCarousel);     
});
```

I have then added some additional css:

```
.dev7-caroufredsel-wrapper {
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 560px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        align-content:center !important;
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-carousel img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-prev, .dev7-caroufredsel-next {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
            display: block;
            height: 560px;
            width: 45.4%;
            top: 0;
            position: absolute;
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-prev:hover, .dev7-caroufredsel-next:hover {
            background-color: #fff;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-prev {
            left: -495px;
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-next {
            right: -495px;
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-pag {
            margin-left: -550px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 10px;
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-pag a {
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-pag a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-pag a span {
            display: none;
}

.dev7-caroufredsel-pag a.selected {
            background-color: #fff;
}
```

Please forgive me if I haven't included enough details, this is my first post on here...if you need anything else then please do ask.

Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the problem is really about the pager -try to change :

```
.dev7-caroufredsel-pag {
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 8%;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

and why not set in `function runCarousel()` `responsive: true`

Comment: Many thanks however that didn't work - it is still not aligning in the center.  To make it easier I was thinking of making only 1 item visible when on mobile devices, thus, in theory, meaning it can't show another image to the side.  Do you think this would work?  I don't know how to implement this if so!! just thinking on my feet...